# C# - Moving a Image(Car) from point a to b without using timer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am new to c#. I have to tried to move an image from point a to b using linear interpolation formula with timer and it worked on an update.

However I am thinking is there anyway possible to do the same without timer. Is it possible?

Here is my Sample Code.

```
if (Car_move == true)
{
 x = Convert.ToInt32(Source.X + time * (Dest.X - Source.X));
 y = Convert.ToInt32(Source.Y + time * (Dest.Y - Source.Y));
 G.DrawImage(Car, x - 10, y - 10, 20, 20);
 if ((Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x - Source.X), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(y - 
   Source.Y), 2)))) >= Distance)
 {
  x = Dest.X;
  y = Dest.Y;
  Car_move = false;           
  }
} 


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (time >= 1)
 {
   time -= 1;
 }
   time +=0.02f;
   panel1.Refresh();
   Invalidate();
}
```

This is what I have tried. I am still trying to figure out to do the same without using timer.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Sure, but we are here to help with code.  Please post code of what you have tried?

Comment: @Nag: Put it in the question. Much more space, and the option of proper formatting. No one can read what you just pasted in your comment.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - What is your issue with Timer?

Comment: Whats the problem with timer?

Comment: @Jelman: for my further work where I am planning to implement collision avoidance for a static obstacle, i don't know yet whether timer control would be helpful or not

Comment: @TaW my mistake I kinda messed up while editing

Comment: OK. Can we assume the code is happening in the Paint/OnPaint event? - But that still doesn't really explain why to avoid Timer. You can and should always try to separate the event level and the action tirggered from it so you can exchange the event controller, e.g. to a different timer type. Btw: There should be no need for the Refresh and it will most likely hurt performance.

Comment: @TaW Yes its in Paint event and without Refresh i don't see any movement. To avoid timer, is a choice and I am trying to know, if there is a way out.

Comment: Whoops I missed the basic error in the code: You need to Invalidate the control you have coded the Paint event of but invalidate the form. Looks like this is the `panel1`? Again: Do not leave out the event header!! And call panel1.Invalidate()! I aslo hope that `G=e.Graphics` and not some creategraphics crap object !!??

Comment: @TaW oh ya i didn't Invalidate. Thanks that helped and yes its G=e.Graphics

Comment: @Trey Sample code

Comment: @Nag, if you could elaborate on what you are looking for, may be we think better. All we are doing now is finding clever ways, which though dont solve anything. The way i see it, you need your paint code to run at definite intervals. This needs a timer to generate those intervals. It seems you are working on a simulation (collision). In most game/simulation engine, timer _is_ an integral part. So what is it that you are looking for? Or what problem of timer is that you want to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many choices, one is a simple loop with a wait/sleep in it.  Another would be to do event driven, such as your car.move property, every time that is changed, you could fire off your paint. Or task.continuewith(would not be my first choice...
Loop:

```
 bool StopRunning = false;
            while (!StopRunning)
            {
                panel.Invalidate();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

Comment: an example would help

Comment: There, simple loop, that will trigger your paint every 1 second.  Adjust as needed.

Comment: While this is certainly an idea, in practice this might not work as good. You are either invalidating or sleeping but never actually painting. The whole ui might act freezed!

Comment: lol not true, but I get your point.  Having done this code.. but yes, async or throw a doevents

Answer (score 2):

Try asynchrony.

Create new Windows Forms project, place this code in form constructor. Run app, click on form. Car is moving! Yeah!

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();

    var Car = new PictureBox { Parent = this, BackColor = Color.Green };

    this.Click += async (s, e) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Car.Top++;
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the animation starts, you could store the time:

```
private DateTime animationStarted;

public void StartAnimation()
{
    animationStarted = DateTime.Now;
    Car_move = true;
    Invalidate();
}
```

This way you don't have to depend on a timer to update the elapsed time. You can simply call `Invalidate()` from the `Paint` handler to paint often while keeping a responsive window:

```
public void My_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    double elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(animationStarted).TotalMilliseconds;

    // ... current paint code

    if (Car_move)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to TaW's comment that you need to `Invalidate()` the control at which the painting happens, if this is `panel1` you'd need `panel1.Invalidate()`.

Comment: In this the animation speed will not be consistent.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis i would try this